# Communicating between python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python

So I have two projects, one python, and one javascript that I want to be able to communicate. I have tried [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/), but it is not working, the request.get_json() is returning none and I have tried all sorts of things that either break it or lead to that NoneType problem again.

All I want is to be able to have a python service running, that allows get or post calls from javascript. So that data entered into the javascript application can be submitted to the python program which does some manipulation and then sends it back.

Any links to resources or examples of doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `the request.get_json()` what is that? You need to post code if you have trouble with code

Comment: Without code, we have no idea what you're actually doing, so in complete absence of any usable information: tell python to run a web server, and make node (I assume you mean node, "javascript" is not both a language and interpreter) talk to python using standard URL calls.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is simply passing data through [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), albeit on a localhost (I guess). Anyways whether you are passing data over internet or on your localhost, the semantics are the same, so I suggest you read more about AJAX

Comment: Google Flask tutorials. The tutorial you're following is using Flask, which is designed for small apps, so if you fgoogle that, find some beginner tutorials, you should find your way.